# prevent fragment create view everytime after tabhost switched

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabhost

I'm using `TabHost` with fragment. I found the onCreateView of the inside fragmens called every time after the `TabHost` switched. Some of the views are complicate. Is there any to keep the view in fragment not just keep the view state?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the solution here. First time we create the view and store it as a instance variable. Then next time the onCreateView called. We just need to check if it's null and remove it from original parent.